# Which Collaboration Software Do You Use?

Tags: agile, pm-software, project-team, time-management, reporting

We are looking for a new Collaboration-Software. Especially for collaboration, monitoring, reporting, project management, bugtracking, time management, agile software etc.

So I am interested in your choice? Which software do you use?

Comment: Hi @Sedro, welcome to PMSE, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers. Please be sure to check the [pm-software](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag. It's very likely that someone asked this question here before and that the answers already exist on our site. Again, welcome to PMSE; I hope you continue to participate on our site!

Comment: Agree w/ @jmort253. A good question... that has been already answered several times in several ways. Maybe putting some more details on the specific requirements could make this question more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a bit of different tools you mentioned up there.  So I will just hit on a couple of tools that I use:

1) Card Wall.  Yes, I know it is low tech, but the visibility and collaboration this brings to team is great.  Otherwise, you are expecting someone to log into a piece of software every day to perform some actions.

2) Software that I really enjoy: 
Agile - RallyDev, Mingle, VersionOne
Task Management: Asana (Free) 
Other: Trello (Free)

Other's I've heard, but have no experience with: Jira, BaseCamp

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) for a number of projects, which is a software for scrum management. With backlog, planning poker, iterations, user stories, burn down charts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We use the BaseCamp suite.

We had used Trac and a variety of other applications as well - but we ended up sticking with this.

BaseCamp, Highrise, Backpack and Campfire

Campfire as a chat system for intercompany chat is very useful and it logs all the transcripts so they can be referenced in projects and cases.

The structure of the suite is intended to get the menial tasks of documentation out of the way and get down to getting stuff done.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) (free and open source) and [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) (paid) as I've used both before and find they help improve collaboration and project management as well as offer issue tracking, reporting and SCM integration.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [**KanbanTool**](http://kanbantool.com/) - a smart software with a long list of features that support real-time team collaboration:

- team collaboration with real-time updates
- advanced account access privileges (full, custom & read-only access)
- advanced sharing options: sharing folders, boards and online
  documents
- build teams and assign tasks to team members
- email notifications for task assignments and comments
- add tasks and comments via email
- create, edit and share documents
- additional info field on Kanban board for teams

...and a lot [more](http://kanbantool.com/product)... Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

We use [HyperOffice](http://www.hyperoffice.com), but it comes more from the collaboration side than the project management side. You get document management, project management, workflows, web forms, pages, wikis etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we are looking to implement an Open-Source kit, called XPlanner+:

http://xplanner-plus.sourceforge.net/

At the moment we are only using the standard Excel Planning template you can download for burning down work. Now we are looking into Stories, we have decided to use something alittle more sophisticated.