# What tools do you use for distributed scrum backlog/board

Tags: scrum, software-development, distributed-team, backlog

Which tools do you guys use for your distributed scrum teams?

I have had a look at Jira, Teamspace, Scrumworks and wanted to know if there any others used in the community. If possible please state the good and the bad of the tool you are using.
Thanks you in advance

Comment: Hi GETah, welcome to PMSE, the Q&A site for project managers. In general, we try to avoid questions that "poll" the community for lists of their favorite software. Asking things like "Which tools do YOU use" are not constructive because the list provided doesn't solve a real problem. It looks like you got a good answer though, but if you need more, consider making an [edit] to your question to ask for more specifics, something that could lead to a more concrete set of answers. Edited questions can be flagged for reopening, if needed. Again, welcome to PMSE, and good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question/answer where you may find more ideas:

[Which Collaboration Software Do You Use?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/4617/468)

The tool is one thing, and how you use it is a completely different one. Doing Scrum with distributed teams is more than challenging. Even the CSM trainer said that it was not possible. He suggested to have two teams, separate boards, and a well organized product backlog so that the teams wouldn't block each other. If you believe in this you won't need a tool for a shared board, but you'll need a something for the backlog, which can support concurrent access. We are working like this at the moment, and our backlog is in JIRA.

However, I know a team, where the team members are working remotely and they are using trello to keep in sync. There a small communication overhead for them, which is still cheaper than working together in an office.